# Porting iOS to Mac, recreate GUI, UMEKIT or Chamelon?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios, macos

I'm currently porting a project from iOS to Mac.
I wrote big parts of the code in C++ so I only need to get a new UI (and get back the mouse!)

But, since our product manager said the application should look the same on both platforms
(It's mainly a viewer for drawings). I figured porting should be worth a try.
I wanted to know if anyone used UMEKIT or Chamelon open source project for this porting and can share insights...

Any guideline howto's use them or is it a big no no?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you don't want to have your app listed [here](https://www.tumblr.com/privacy/consent?redirect=http://readthefuckinghig.tumblr.com/).

**For every new platform you release an application, recreate the user interface completely, from scratch.** People, especially Mac users want consistency between applications, so it's best to do it the Mac-way. Also see the [Human Interface Guidelines for Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/XHIGIntro/XHIGIntro.html).

I mean, this is awful:

[image: pic]
<sub>(source: [tumblr.com](http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_levam3N5k01qg62t3o1_500.png))</sub>

---

<sup><sub>Does your product manager use a Mac?</sub></sup>

Comment: Yeah well, sadly I am not in a position to make that call but thanks for your input.

Comment: I upvoted it for you! and marked answered! With your comment they decided to recreate the UI :)